# XNA - Hold longer to jump higher (example attached)

Tags: c#, xna

I recently asked a question, but still don't understand, I mean the answers were great, but I just don't understand. I'm trying to make the player jump higher the longer the space bar is held for. There also needs to be a max on the height.

I have a player class example, and I'm trying to add such a function to this. If someone could take a look at this class, add the function and then perhaps add some comments to help me out, I would very much appreciate that. - Thank you.

Player.cs

```
namespace Jumping
```

{

```
class Player
{
    public Texture2D Texture;

    public Vector2 Velocity;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public float ground;
    private float Speed;

    private Rectangle screenBound;

    public bool isJumping; //are we jumping or not
    public bool goingUp; //if going up or not

    public float u; //initial velocity
    private float jumpU;
    private float g; //gravity
    public float t; //time

    private KeyboardState prevKB;

    public Player(Texture2D Texture, Vector2 Position, float Speed, Rectangle screenBound)
    {
        this.Texture = Texture;
        this.Position = Position;
        ground = Position.Y;
        this.Speed = Speed;
        this.screenBound = screenBound;
        Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        isJumping = goingUp = false;
        jumpU = 2.5f;
        g = -9.8f;
        t = 0;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        Position.X += (Velocity.X * Speed);
        //Set the Y position to be subtracted so that the upward movement would be done by decreasing the Y value
        Position.Y -= (Velocity.Y * Speed);

        goingUp = (Velocity.Y > 0);

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        if (isJumping == true)
        {
            //motion equation using velocity: v = u + at
            Velocity.Y = (float)(u + (g * t));
            //Increase the timer
            t += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if (isJumping == true && Position.Y > screenBound.Height - Texture.Height)
        {
            Position.Y = ground = screenBound.Height - Texture.Height;
            Velocity.Y = 0;
            isJumping = false;
            t = 0;
        }

        if (Position.X < 0)
        {
            //if Texture touches left side of the screen, set the position to zero and the velocity to zero.
            Position.X = 0;
            Velocity.X = 0;
        }
        else if (Position.X    + Texture.Width > screenBound.Width)
        {
            //if Texture touches left side of the screen, set the position to zero and the velocity to zero.
            Position.X = screenBound.Width - Texture.Width;
            Velocity.X = 0;
        }
        if (Position.Y < 0)
        {
            //if the Texture touches the top of the screen, reset the timer and set the initial velocity to zero.
            Position.Y = 0;
            t = 0;
            u = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Input(KeyboardState keyState)
    {
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && (isJumping == false || Position.Y == ground))
        {
            isJumping = true;
            u = jumpU;
        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && !keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                if (Velocity.X > -2.0f)
                Velocity.X -= (1.0f / 10);
            }
            else if (Velocity.X > -1.0f)
            {
                Velocity.X -= (1.0f / 10);
            }
            else
            {
                Velocity.X = -1.0f;
            }
        }
        else if (!keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                if (Velocity.X < 2.0f)
                Velocity.X += (1.0f / 10);
            }
            else if (Velocity.X < 1.0f)
            {
                Velocity.X += (1.0f / 10);
            }
            else
            {
                Velocity.X = 1.0f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Velocity.X > 0.05 || Velocity.X < -0.05)
                Velocity.X *= 0.90f;
            else
                Velocity.X = 0;
        }

        prevKB = keyState;
    }

    public void Fall()
    {
        t = 0;
        u = 0;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height), Color.White);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Agreed, don't start another question.

Comment: So I decided to take my time and help you on the last question, but instead you just make a duplicate on how your last answers didn't help? How is this going to get you anywhere? If you leave a comment on my answer for your last question, I might be able to help fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you and don't confuse you, I will suggest an approach but it must be refactored later.

In your Input method, adds it:

```
public void Input(KeyboardState keyState)
{
   newIsJumping = keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);

   ...
```

And in your Update method, use it:

```
// TODO: Add your update logic here
if (isJumping == true)
{
   if (newIsJumping) u += 0.5f; // use some constant here

   ...
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but I've added this into the player.cs and I'm getting error:
The name 'newIsJumping' does not exist in the current context. What do I declare the newIsJumping as?

Comment: I think it's the same as isJumping. So a bool

Comment: Thanks robson roase | PhaDaPhunk 
top lads.